# Do not apply media queries when resizing the browser window with js css

Tags: css, resize, media-queries

Am building now a website which has an animated section with specific background so elements are positioned according to that background with absolute positioning.

For different desktop resolutions i fixed the positioning with css media queries by specific window width/height. So now when user resize with browser window there are some ranges width/height wise where elements are crushed cause i cant just check by every single pixel.

Is there a way to apply the media queries only for real desktop devices so when user resizes the browser i just set some specific width/height to the wrapper with scrolling?

Any other ideas for such type of website sections?

So far i found only the below code which is not working

```
var size = [1440,900];
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    window.resizeTo(size[0],size[1]);
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show what you done so far so that will get a clear picture.

Comment: i updated my question @SarathHari but i really have no clue how to figure out

Comment: absolute position can easily made responsive using top, left, right , bottom. Can you provide the jsfiddle ?

Comment: Yes now also am adjusting it like that but i cant check every single pixel width/height and adjust per it?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sarathhari/x3cpp78b/ Please check the link. Here i don't need to adjust the block in every pixel .These are also position absolute divs.So without seeing criteria its difficult to explain.

Comment: Ok i understand. Here is my website link http://imaginawp.ipoint.com.mt/ @SarathHari

Answer (score 0):

I had alook into your website and what i found is you are using % to top and left for each elements try to use px so that it ill be fixed.

```
.diamondOneAnimatedArea {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    width: 190px;
    top: 35%;
    left: 0%;
}
```

Comment: With pixel effect will be the same i will need to adjust for pixel @Sarath Hari

Comment: You need to rework on the website by removing the margins you set on each pixels too.Building of html with lot of elements is like making a castle with cards.So there is no other ways according to me.

Comment: If i remove margins and add top, bottom it will have same effect as i see